# How to measure the power of two small solar panels independently and combine the power?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, kicad

I am trying to make the connection below. I want to measure the voltages coming from the solar panels connected to pins 2 and 3 and then deliver their combined power at pin 1 in the teal square.

I believe that with this configuration the voltages of pins 2 and 3 will be the same because they are connected downstream. Is there a way to prevent this and get an accurate reading of each panel individually?

[image]

Comment: why do you need to combine 2 : 1 signals then separate? Is this for Logic?

Comment: There is no easy answer because "combine" can look very different, depending on the rest of the circuit. Please provide more context about current flow directions, expected voltages and allowed power losses in "combine".

Comment: @Jens pins 2 and 3 are pins of an Arduino, the wires going into them are from two different solar panels. I am trying to measure each panel's voltages and then use both of them to power the circuit with pin 1. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MasonWright This "combine" is typically done with two schottky diodes. Pin 2 and 3 are connected to the anodes and the cathodes meet at pin1. But if you do so, the difference in voltage will be very low. Your intention to measure them independent is (nearly) impossible this way.

Comment: @Jens Thank you that makes sense, is there a method I could use to measure it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a very simple and cheap first approach**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn2icD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is much easier to measure the individual current of the panels than the voltage.

1. Schottky diodes D1 and D2 combine the individual currents. The voltage sum is at SUM_PANEL+. Other Schottky diodes are OK as well (e.g. 1N5819)
2. There is a synbolic load resistor R_LOAD powered by the panels.
3. Each panel has a small shunt resistor in the negative path to measure the current of the panel (R1, R2). The current calculation is I = U/R, we know R and the Arduino will measure U. A shunt of 0.1 ohm is good for 1A panels, smaller panels will need bigger shunt values (e.g. 1 ohm for 100 mA)
4. We need a trick to measure the voltages. Professional solutions use differential amplifiers here, but this is a simple solution. The voltages across R1 and R2 are negative relative to GND. So we cannot connect them directly to the analog inputs of the Arduino, they would be damaged. Two voltage dividers (R6 R4 and R7 R5) will add 0.45V to the shunt voltage. This is a safe operating condition for the Arduino.
5. To setup the system, the software must measure the voltages once without the panels connected. This is the baseline value for "no current" and must be noted. With connected panels the measured values are lower than the baseline, more current is lower value.
6. The current of a panel is I = U/R = (U_baseline - U_measured) / R
7. To estimate the power of a panel, the current must be multiplied with the voltage at SUM_PANEL. This may be above 5 V, so it is halved by the divider R8 R9.

This circuit has some inprecisions (voltage error introduced by divider, power calculation ignoring diode and shunt drops, panel as voltage source in the simulator etc.). I just want to show a start path. The simulator shows the conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much! this is a perfect starting point!